# JsonProperty annotation does not work for Json parsing in Scala (Jackson/Jerkson)

Tags: json, scala, jackson, jerkson

I need to parse the following json string:

> {"type": 1}

The case class I am using looks like:

```
case class MyJsonObj(
    val type: Int
)
```

However, this confuses Scala since 'type' is a keyword. So, I tried using @JsonProperty annotation from Jacson/Jerkson as follows:

```
case class MyJsonObj(
    @JsonProperty("type") val myType: Int
)
```

However, the Json parser still refuses to look for 'type' string in json instead of 'myType'. Following sample code illustrates the problem:

```
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate._

case class MyJsonObj(
    @JsonProperty("type") val myType: Int
)

object SimpleExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val jsonLine = """{"type":1}"""
    val JsonObj = parse[MyJsonObj](jsonLine)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
[error] (run-main-a) com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException: Invalid JSON. Needed [myType], but found [type].
```

P.S: As seen above, I am using jerkson/jackson, but wouldn't mind switching to some other json parsing library if that makes life easier.

Answer (score 5):

Use backquotes to prevent the Scala compiler from interpreting type as the keyword:

```
case class MyJsonObj(
    val `type`: Int
)
```

Comment: Although that would work, I am really looking for the reason why @JsonProperty annotation didn't work as expected. Also, I want the val name to be more meaningful than just 'type'.

Comment: This may be an issue with Scala making all fields private and automatically generating getter and setter methods. You might be able to use Scala's [meta annotations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package). What happens if you replace `@JsonProperty("type")` with `@(JsonProperty("type") @field @getter @setter)`?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you aren't enabling Scala support in Jackson properly.

I've tried this:

```
object Test extends App {

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  println(mapper.writeValueAsString(MyJsonObj(1)))

  val obj = mapper.readValue("""{"type":1}""", classOf[MyJsonObj])
  println(obj.myType)
}

case class MyJsonObj(@JsonProperty("type") myType: Int)
```

And I get:

```
{"type":1}
1
```

Note that I've added Scala support to the object mapper by calling `registerModule`

Answer (score 3):

As @wingedsubmariner implied, the answer lies with [Scala meta annotations](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/meta/index.html).

This worked for me:

```scala
import scala.annotation.meta.field

case class MyJsonObj(
    @(JsonProperty @field)("type") val myType: Int
)
```

This is in addition to `mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)`, which you'll probably need if you're deserializing into a Scala class.